# How does AWS Application Load balancer select a target within a target group? How to load balance the websocket traffic?

Tags: websocket, load-balancing, amazon-elb

I have an AWS Application load balancer to distribute the http(s) traffic.

Problem 1:

Suppose I have a target group with 2 EC2 instances: micro and xlarge. Obviously they can handle different traffic levels. Does the load balancer manage traffic proportionally to instance sizes or just round robin? If only round robin is used and no other factors taken into account, then it's not really balancing load, because at some point the micro instance will be suffering from the traffic, while xlarge will starve.

Problem 2:

Suppose I have target group with 2 EC2 instances, both are same size. But my service is not using a classic http request/response flow. It is using HTTP websockets, i.e. a client makes HTTP request just once, to establish a socket, and then keeps the socket open for longer time, sending and receiving messages (e.g. a chat service). Let's suppose my load balancer is using round robin and both EC2 instances have 1000 clients connected each. Now suppose one of the EC2 instances goes down and 1000 connected clients drop their socket connections. The instance gets back up quickly and is ready to accept websocket calls again. The 1000 clients who dropped are trying to reconnect. Now, if the load balancer would use pure round robin, I'll end up with 1500 clients connected to instance #1 and 500 clients connected to instance #2, thus not really balancing the load correctly.

Basically, I'm trying to find out if some more advanced logic is being used to select a target in a group, or is it just a naive round robin selection. If it's round robin only, then how can I really balance the websocket connections load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Websockets** start out as http or https connections, so a load balancer can dispatch them to a server. Once the server accepts the http connection, both the server and the client "upgrade" the connection to use the websocket protocol.  They then leave the connection open to use for websocket traffic. As far as the load balancer can tell, the connection is simply a long-lasting http connection.

Taking a server down when it has websocket connections to clients requires your application to retry lost connections. Reconnecting on connection failure is one of the trickiest parts of websocket client programming. Your application cannot be robust without reconnect logic.

**AWS's load balancer** has no built-in knowledge of the capabilities of the servers behind it. You have observed that it sends requests equally to big and small servers. That can overwhelm the small ones.

I have managed this by building a **/healthcheck endpoint** in my servers. It's a straightforward https://example.com/heathcheck web page. You can put a little bit of content on the page announcing how many websocket connections are currently open, or anything else. Don't password protect it or require a session to hit it.

My /healthcheck endpoints, whenever hit, measure the server load. I simply use the number of current websocket connections, but you can use any metric you want. I compare the current load to a load threshold configured for each server.  For example, on a micro instance I can handle 20 open websockets, and on a production instance I can handle 400.

If the server load is too high, my endpoint gives back a [503 http error status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/503) along with its content. 503 typically means "I am overloaded, please try again later." It can also mean "I will shut down when all my connections are closed. Please don't use me for any more connections."

Then I **[configure the load balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/target-group-health-checks.html) to perform those health checks** every couple of minutes on all the servers in the server pool (AWS calls the pool a "target group"). The health check operation detects "unhealthy" servers and temporarily takes them out of its rotation.  (The health check also detects crashed servers, which is good.)

You need this loadbalancer health check for a large-scale production setup.

All that being said, you will get best results if all your server instances in your pool have roughly the same capacity as each other.

Comment: So, does that mean that load balancers are using round robin selection only? What you wrote makes sense and would probably work, but isn't this an abuse of a health check feature? An instance will be visible in the AWS console as 'unhealthy'  while in fact it is fully functional and operating normally. It should work, but it may be a little bit confusing to person looking at the health check statuses. Another downside is that the machine itself must know when to return HTTP 503, i.e. know upfront how much load it can take, and this logic needs to be "hardcoded" somewhere.

Comment: I thought it could be configured somewhere in the target group options, like, a drop down list "load balancing policy", with options like "Round Robin", "Number of Open Connections", "Average CPU load" etc... It would solve all the issues immediately, for all scenarios. But I could not find any info on that, and it's kind of disturbing to know that round robin is the default option and the only option...

Comment: This is no abuse of the health check feature. On the contrary it is one of the most important uses of that feature.  If you need a different kind of console health status, create a different health endpoint for the purpose.